# Error con barra menu Boostrap data-hover="dropdown"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Muy buenas, tengo una barra de menú de Boostrap que en parte se genera con una función javascript, el resultado de la funcion lo meto en un div de la barra que se llama menuCategorias. Mi intención es añadirle funcionalidad   data-hover="dropdown" Para que al pasar el cursor se desplieguen las acciones.

La funcion  `menuCat();` se llama desde el `$(document).ready`
Esta función genera las opciones de la barra y muestra los enlaces de las subCategorias Correspondientes. Esta función por un lado toma los nombres de las categorias, y por otro lado, la función submenucat, genera los desplegables de cada categoria. La idea es que pasar por la categoria, se despliegue la subcategorias correspondientes. Todo esto lo hace bien haciendo click.

```js
function menuCat(){
  $.ajax ({
    //Grupo Categorias
    url: "php/AgrApp/grp_cat.php",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
      //Aqui tengo el json con todas las categorias
      objJsonCat=JSON.parse(data);
      subMenuCat("", function(idSubCategoria){
        var menuCate='<ul class="nav navbar-nav">';
        $.each(objJsonCat, function(i, categoria) {
          menuCate+='<li class="dropdown">'+
                    ' <a  class="dropdown-toggle"'+ 
                    '     data-toggle="dropdown"' +
                    '     data-hover="dropdown">' +
                    '   <b>'+categoria.name+'</b>' +
                    '   <b class="caret"></b>'+
                    ' </a>'+
                    ' <ul class="dropdown-menu">';
          indice=0;
          $.each(idSubCategoria, function(j, subCategoria) {
            //Hago un for desde 0 hasta la longitud de esa Subcategoria.
            if (subCategoria.grp_cat==categoria.id){
              menuCate+= '<li>'+
                         '  <a data-toggle="collapse"' +
                         '     data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"' +
                         '     onClick="categorias('+categoria.id+','+indice+');'+                          '              return false;"' +
                         '     data-toggle="collapse"' + 
                         '     data-target="navbar-collapse.in">' +' 
                         '    <b>'+subCategoria.name+'</b>'+ 
                         '  </a>'+ 
                         '</li>'+
                         //Pinto la subCategoria
                         '<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>';
                         //le paso el indice a la funcion categorias para
                         //que sepa cual tiene que activar
              indice++; 
             }
          });
          menuCate+='</ul> </li>';
        });
        $('#menuCategorias').html(menuCate); 
      });
    }   
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/2.2.1/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!--
    El logotipo y el icono que despliega el menú se agrupan
    para mostrarlos mejor en los dispositivos móviles
  -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button"
            class="navbar-toggle"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-hover="dropdown"
            data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">
        Desplegar navegación
      </span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a onClick="categorias(); return false;"
       class="navbar-brand"
       href="#">
      <b>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span>
        Categorías
      </b>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- 
    Agrupar los enlaces de navegación, los formularios y cualquier
    otro elemento que se pueda ocultar al minimizar la barra
  -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <div class="cursor"
           id="menuCategorias">
      </div>
      <!--
        Aqui es donde se carga el contenido el menu de gategorias
      -->
    </ul>
    <div class="navbar-form navbar-right"
         role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"
               id="txtConvBus"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="Busqueda por palabras" />
      </div>
      <button id="btnBusqueda"  
              class="btn btn-primary">
        Ir
      </button>
    </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: olle y estas si quiera llamado a la funcion?. ahi veo que no estas llamado a la funcion con la etiqueta `a href`, ademas es `onclick` no `onClick`.

Comment: @lorenzo me parece amigo que debes aportar más código, por ejemplo las funciones `categorias` y `subMenuCat` entre otras cosas.